# Upper bound of absolute value of a complex function $\left||x| - c\right|$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, numerical-linear-algebra, upper-lower-bounds

I have the following relationship:

Given $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$,

we have $\left||x| - c\right| = \left|x - e^{j\angle x}c\right| < \left||x| - e^{j\angle y}c\right| $, where $y \neq x$.

Now can I say $\left|x - e^{j\angle x}c\right| < \left|x - e^{j\angle y}c\right|$ for all $y \neq x$, i.e, to say,

$\left|x - e^{j\angle y}c\right|$ is the upper bound for $\left||x| - c\right|$

Comment: No. Consider the case when $c<0$.

Comment: Sorry I missed the condition $c \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$. Considering this will the condition holds?

Comment: What is $j\angle x$?

Comment: It can be understood as the following $e^{j\angle x} = \frac{x}{|x|}$.

Comment: When $c>0$, you can use the strict inequality whenever $y/|y| \neq x/|x|$.